MD calculation of hexagonal boron nitride using LAMMPS
I use LAMMPS to perform MD calculations for hBN. However, I can't find a suitable tersoff potential file. Where can I get it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
